# Thread notification isn't working for my consumer

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, unique-lock

I have an attempt at a producer/consumer

Producer

```
#pragma once
#ifndef PRODUCER_H
#define PRODUCER_H

#include <thread>
#include "Mailbox.h"

class Producer
{
private:
    std::thread producer;
    Mailbox& mailbox;
public:
    Producer(Mailbox& newmailbox);
    ~Producer();
    void start();
    void run();
};

Producer::Producer(Mailbox& newMailbox) : mailbox(newMailbox) {}

Producer::~Producer() {}

void Producer::start()
{
    producer = std::thread(&Producer::run, this);
}

void Producer::run()
{
    mailbox.inc();
}

#endif
```

Consumer

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONSUMER_H
#define CONSUMER_H

#include "Mailbox.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Consumer
{
private:
    Mailbox& mailbox;
    std::thread consumer;
public:
    Consumer(Mailbox& newMailbox);
    ~Consumer();
    void start();
    void run();
};

Consumer::Consumer(Mailbox& newMailbox) : mailbox(newMailbox) {}


Consumer::~Consumer() {}

void Consumer::start()
{
    consumer = std::thread(&Consumer::run, this);
}

void Consumer::run()
{
    mailbox.read();
}

#endif
```

Mailbox

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MAILBOX_H
#define MAILBOX_H

#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class Mailbox
{
private:
    int& mailbox;
    int init_val;
    std::mutex mmutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
public:
    Mailbox();
    ~Mailbox();
    void inc();
    void read();
};

Mailbox::Mailbox() : mailbox(init_val), init_val(0) {}

Mailbox::~Mailbox()
{

}

void Mailbox::inc()
{   
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mmutex);
        std::cout << "Producer increment\n";
        mailbox += 1;
        lock.unlock();

        count += 1;
    }

}

void Mailbox::read()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mmutex);

        condition.wait(lock, [this](){return get_cflag(); });

        condition.notify_one();

        count += 1;

    }

}

#endif
```

Main

```
int main()
{

    Mailbox* mailbox = new Mailbox();
    Consumer* consumer = new Consumer(*mailbox);
    Producer* producer = new Producer(*mailbox);

    consumer->start();
    producer->start();

    return 0;
}
```

Mutex locking works albeit asynchronously because I have no control over when a `std::thread` will start so I decided to implement a semi-synchronous methodology using `std::unique_lock` in addition to `std::mutex`.

Problem is, the Consumer waits and the Producer flies on ahead with no notification at least that is what the debugger is telling me and the last Producer iteration result sin a n abort() so something is going wrong here.

Comment: Nowhere do any of your threads ever check whether or not they need to wait for anything. Specifically, your `read` function calls `wait` without checking whether it needs to wait and then proceeds after `wait` returns without checking whether it needs to wait. Condition variables are stateless -- it's your job to check whether you need to wait both before deciding to call `wait` and before deciding to proceed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Given your comment, I did some more research and read through `C++ Concurrency In Action (Anthony Williams) an approachable solution.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I corrected the int mailbox reference to int& mailbox and the copy assignment I haven't completed yet.

Comment: @Mushy instead of letting the mailbox have a reference to int, have the consumer and producer take a reference to a mailbox. This is because you need to reuse the same mutex (which is not copyable) to safeguard the access to the mailbox-storage

Comment: @WorldSEnder They are, I just haven't taken updates on my local and posted them here -- I will now

Answer (score 0):

I’m not a C++ guy, but if these condition variables work the way I think they do, you’ll only get notified if a signal arrives *while you’re waiting*.  If the signal arrived *before* you started waiting, you’ll block indefinitely.

After you acquire the lock in 'Mailbox::read`, you should check to see if an item is available, and only wait on the condition variable if there *isn’t* one.  If there is, go ahead and take it:

```
int Mailbox::read()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    while (mailbox <= 0)
        condition.wait(lock);
    return mailbox--;
}
```

Comment: His `read` functions calls `wait` even if the thing he is waiting for has already happened. And when `wait` returns, it assumes that the thing he was waiting for has happened. You *MUST* check -- the condition variable does not know whether or not the thing you are waiting for has happened. It's your job to track that.

Comment: I changed the producer and consumer functions to incorporate lambda expressions with wait using a simple flag to signal readiness or wait.  Thank you Mike and David.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon David Schwartz's comment, insight from Mike Strobel, and additional research, I changed the producer and consumer functions

Producer

```
void Mailbox::inc()
{   
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mmutex);
        std::cout << "Producer increment\n";
        mailbox += 1;
        lock.unlock();
        set_cflag(true); // signal to the consumer data is ready
        condition.notify_one();

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mmutex);
            condition.wait(lock, [this]() {return get_pflag(); });
        }

        set_pflag(false);

        count += 1;
    }

}
```

Consumer

```
 void Mailbox::read()
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mmutex);

        condition.wait(lock, [this](){return get_cflag(); });

        std::cout << "Consumer: " << mailbox << "\n";
        lock.unlock();

        set_pflag(true);
        condition.notify_one();

        count += 1;

        set_cflag(false);

    }

}
```

Mailbox

```
class Mailbox
{
private:
    int& mailbox;
    int cflag, pflag;
    int init_val;
    std::mutex mmutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
public:
    Mailbox();
    ~Mailbox();
    int get_cflag() { return cflag; }
    void set_cflag(int newFlag) { cflag = newFlag; }
    int get_pflag() { return pflag; }
    void set_pflag(int newFlag) { pflag = newFlag; }
    void inc();
    void read();
};

Mailbox::Mailbox() : mailbox(init_val), init_val(0), cflag(0), pflag(0) {}

Mailbox::~Mailbox()
{

}
```

The output upon execution is as I desired

```
int main()
{

    Mailbox* mailbox = new Mailbox();
    Consumer* consumer = new Consumer(*mailbox);
    Producer* producer = new Producer(*mailbox);

    consumer->start();
    producer->start();

    fgetc(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 1
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 2
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 3
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 4
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 5
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 6
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 7
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 8
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 9
>
> Producer increment
>
> Consumer: 10

Comment: I am unable to call `std::thread.join()` as `std::thread.terminate()` may have already been called with the class threads exiting the functions and the program terminating

Comment: I was unclear on why the producer and consumer threads were `join`ing themselves.  What effect could that have, other than a no-op or a deadlock?  Typically, the thread that _spawns_ worker threads does the joining.